# Htaccess : url redirection that contains special character

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect this url: 
blog/it’s-now-available-book’s 
to new destination:
new/blog/it’s-now-available-book’s 
but it's failed. I have tried these 2 redirect but none is working:

```
Redirect 301 blog/it\xE2\x80\x99s-now-available-book\xE2\x80\x99s new/blog/it\xE2\x80\x99s-now-available-book\xE2\x80\x99s 
Redirect 301 blog/it’s-now-available-book’s new/blog/it’s-now-available-book’s
```

Comment: You should check your http servers access log file to find out how exactly the incoming request looks like instead of trying around....

Comment: Can you provide example of incoming links and where do you want to redirect them?

Comment: @arkascha when i use this redirect Redirect 301 blog/it’s-now-available-book’s new/blog/it’s-now-available-book’s the error is /var/www/html/panasas/.htaccess: Redirect to non-URL

Comment: @anubhava I want to redirect from this url blog/it’s-now-available-book’s to this url new/blog/it’s-now-available-book’s the problem is the url has this char ’

Comment: Don't get this wrong, but I doubt that you followed my advice and took that url from the log file. Simply because of the fact that such request could _never_ appear in a log file, since that url is indeed invalid. That character following the "it" and "book" cannot occur in a valid url. When entered your browser will send a request, but to a url like this: `/blog/it%E2%80%99s-now-available-book%E2%80%99s` which is valid and can re processed and rewritten. In it that character is replaced by its "percent encoded utf sequence". If you create such urls programmatically, then you have to encode!

Comment: @arkascha i'm using drupal and the url is not encoded, now what should i do to redirect this url?

Comment: Do you really have to redirect that specific URL or is it all URLs in that blog in general? Also: to me the `Redirect` rules you posted look invalid. They do not comply with the argument format as documented. What I read in the documentation is: paths _must_ start with a slash (`/`), so be absolute. Your's don't. So most likely the rules will never get applied. Did you take a look at the documentation yourself? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as very first rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/it\xE2\x80\x99s-now-available-book\xE2\x80\x99s /new/blog/it's-now-available-book's [L,NC,R=302]
```